# OneDrive fails to update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, onedrive

I've noticed CPU sometimes working on over 50% load with having OneDrive setup running in background with no avail for a month or so.

I tried downloading the setup and running it but setup just hangs in "preparing" state and doesn't progress either.

Googling didn't show me anything relevant.

Windows 10 Pro, 1703 Build 15063.483, always updated with latest pathes, 20Gb available on a system drive, more on others.

OneDrive still works but I'd like to have it updated so automatic update won't keep popping up in background making fan speed up and cpu waste electricity for nothing.

Comment: OneDrive is built-into Windows 10.  So running the setup, as expected, does nothing since that client isn't compatible with Windows 10.  OneDrive that's installed is already "updated" or do you mean you want your files to synchronize?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows constantly tries running OneDrive Setup or update process in background and fails while heating my CPU. Sometimes it shows notifications about failed OneDrive update. I want it to stop.

Comment: There is no "setup" to run on Windows 10.  By setup are you saying your getting a prompt to configure your settings.  OneDrive is built into Windows 10.  You already have the current Windows 10 OneDrive client if you have feature update 1703 installed

Comment: @Ramhound I know that it's installed. I'm using it successfully. I want Windows to stop trying to run setup in background.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "setup" it's not possible to "install" OneDrive on Windows 10 it's already installed out of the box unless you removed it from your installation image

Comment: If your going to be rude to me I cannot help you.

Comment: have you tried the fix from my answer in the duplicate topic?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did and it helped.

Comment: nice to hear this. what is your username path? Also with special characters?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It does have Unicode characters, yes.